# Call Stack in SAP Hana

Tags: multithreading, stack, hana

Are there any table/view/procedure where we access the call stack in a procedure?

For instance, I'm calling procedure B in procedure A and I would like to get which procedure is calling procedure B.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is nothing that directly would provide you with this sort of call-hierarchy. The main reason for that is, that even though you call a procedure/function from another procedure and so on, SAP HANA will try and unfold these procedures to make up the optimal minimal data flow graphs. 
That means (depending on your procedure coding), parts of procedures may be merged into a single SQL statement or compiled into a HANA internal language.

The closest thing for you to understand the actual call hierarchy will be to use the PlanViz visualisation on the top-most procedure/function call.

If you want to use the caller information actively in your code, you might want to think about using session variables to keep that information.